# Elasticsearch process run under weird username

Tags: elasticsearch

I have Elasticsearch 1.7.3 running successfully on CentOS7. However, I observed:

```
%ps -aux | grep elastic

**209**      10504 85.0 29.2 36122740 19283600 ?   SLl  04:02   0:05 
/usr/bin/java -Xms30g -Xmx30g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC  
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75   
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError   
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Delasticsearch -Des.pidfile=/var  
/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch
```

As we can see userid is 209. It supposed to be elasticsearch or root right ?

Comment: And what user is id 209 on your system?

Comment: Features I never knew existed: "If the length of the username is greater than the length of the display column, the numeric user ID is displayed instead." So it's quite possible it's `elasticsearch` after all.